# I can delete files in shell when in the directory, but I get a File not found error from outside the directory

Tags: shell, command-line, del

I know this is a rudimentary question, but I am dumbfounded.

Let us say that I have two files in the following directory structure:
`C:\Program Files\Program\Directory\Subdirectory\one.txt` and `C:\Program Files\Program\Directory\Subdirectory\Subsubdirectory\two.txt`

When I run the following command in shell, I get `File not found` errors...

```
del C:\Program Files\Program\Directory\Subdirectory\one.txt C:\Program Files\Program\Directory\Subdirectory\Subsubdirectory\two.txt
```

I have also tried wrapping the file path and names in quotes with no success.

I have also tried a simple test on two files sitting on a user desktop without success: `C:\Users\User\Desktop\one.txt` and `...\two.txt` etc.

For reference, I want to push a script which will remove the maintenance and update functionality from Firefox to prevent users from getting update messages etc, automatic updates and to break the functionality should someone find out how to try [I am also running mKiosk extension], and I want to push the script using SOTI MobiControl software.

Comment: Just noticed: Please remove the 'shell' tag from your post. This is tag usually applies to question covering the Posix Shell, not any of the Windows shells.

Answer (score 0):

You have spaces in your command path. You need to quote your arguments:

```
del "C:\Program Files\Program\Directory\Subdirectory\one.txt"
```

Comment: Thanks for your post - I ought to have included the information that: if I try to delete only 1 file, it works - but not 2 files: `del "C:\Program Files\Program\Directory\Subdirectory\one.txt" "C:\Program Files\Program\Directory\Subdirectory\Subsubdirectory\two.txt"` does not work for me

Comment: Can't be, if it is the standard DEL command from Windows. If you replace DEL by DIR, does it show both files? If you replace DEL by ERASE, do you still get the same error? What 'shell' are you using? Windows Batch, or Windows Power Shell?

Answer (score 0):

I have not found a solution to this syntax issue - however the problem is solved by the functionality of the SOTI Mobicontroler software.

In the package/script delivery, I am writing individual `del` commands for each file. SOTI appears to handle each script line one at a time and sequentially.